# Applied Image Styles Cause Failed Image Render

Tags: 8, media, theming

I'm using Aquia Dev on Windows 10 for a local installation and after the latest Drupal 8 update (8.2 to 8.3), applying image styles to content now causes my images to fail to render.

Checking debug and the directory, the paths `site/MY-SITE/files/styles/MY-STYLES` are correct and the images are there, but for whatever reason Drupal can't pull the images. The alt text is displayed instead. Image-styles that were applied to items before the update still render correctly, but changing the styles on the correctly rendering images thereafter again breaks them.

Most of the information I have found is geared toward changing "775" ownership on a Unix platform. I can't figure out what that means and translate it to a Windows set up.

Comment: Can you please check if you have anything in error log... The images are being generated so image generation library like GD, ImageMagick etc seems to be working fine. Could be an issue with .htaccess file in folder too.

Comment: There are no error logs being reported and Drupal is able to access the node that holds the images, so maybe it is the .htaccess? What setting in there would cause something like this?

Answer (score 0):

These aren't private files, right? There is [an open issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2797639) for something that sounds a lot like this. We applied patch #34 and it resolved the problem for us.